# Where is the NHibernate 3.0 source repository?

Tags: nhibernate

I've been looking everywhere.  Maybe I'm just really nearsighted but I can't seem to find it anywhere.  Link anyone?

Comment: You found the trunk? http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/

And here's ayende's latest change: http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate?view=rev&revision=4966

But there is no mention of 3.0 anywhere.

Answer (score 10):

NHibernate 3.0 is also known as the trunk.  It has not been officially released yet.

You can find the source code in SVN here:

https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/

The main website for NHibernate is here:

http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx

If you wanted to download binaries for the trunk instead of source, you could try here:

http://www.hornget.net/packages/orm/nhibernate/nhibernate-trunk

Comment: NHibernate 3.0 was officially released on December 4, 2010.